# Android - Initialize variable with currently set preference

Tags: java, android, open-source

`private int mShuffleMode = SharedPreferences.getInt("shufflemode");`

Tells me that a Non-static method can't be referenced from a static context.

I'm not entirely sure what this means.

What I'm trying to do is initialise the variable with the preference that was set before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getInt()` is not a method that you call on the *class* `SharedPreferences`. Rather, you call it on an *instance* of `SharedPreferences`.

> What I'm trying to do is initialise the variable with the preference that was set before.

Retrieve your `SharedPreferences` object, then call `getInt()` on that. If you have code that is saving `SharedPreferences`, you should already have access to that `SharedPreferences` object, or at least have code for retrieving it.

See [the documentation on `SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for more.

Comment: Ah! I get it now. Thank you so much for the answer! Once I have 15 rep, I'll be sure to give your response an upvote. This was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can't get data in a static way using `SharedPreferences.getInt("shufflemode");`

What you need to do is create an object of `SharedPreference` and then query it using `SharedPreference sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("name-of-preference",MODE)` and then `sharedPreference.getInt("shufflemode")

Consider this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/9119277)

Answer (score 0):

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPref ;
private int mShuffleMode;
```

> in your `onCreate`

```
sharedPref= context.getSharedPreferences("preferences_file_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mShuffleMode = sharedPref.getInt("shufflemode");
```